# Regexp to pull capitalized words not at the beginning of sentence and two adjacent words

Tags: regex

I want to pull out capitalized words that don't start a sentence along with the previous and following word.

I'm using:

```
(\w*)\b([A-Z][a-z]\w*)\b(\w*)
```

replace with:

```
$1 -- $2 -- $3
```

Edit: It's only returning the $2. Will try suggestions.

And regarding natural language? Don't care for this thing. I just want to see where capitals show up in a sentence so I can figure out if they're proper or not.

Comment: What is the question?  Also, what language are you using?

Comment: Regular expressions can't (correctly) parse English text. Use a natural language parser.

Comment: What if a capitalized word falls at the *end* of the text?  What if there are two capitalized words in a row?  Do you need to account for sentence punctuation, or words with non-alphanumeric characters like `-` and `'` in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This doesn't take into account anything non-alphabetic though. It also assumes that all words are separated by a single whitespace character. You will need to modify it if you want more complex support.

Comment: Careful: `[A-z]` matches a lot more than letters, and a lot less than all valid letters, at least if you're not American.

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm stumped on sentences like "This Is My Capital Letter" - it doesn't seem to match every instance of proper capitalization.

Comment: It may be a problem with the engine. I got the same problem for your example, but trying it on "This Is My Capital Letter Ah Yeah And This Too" in JS gave an array: ["This Is My", "Capital Letter Ah", "Yeah And This"]. It seems to not allow matches to overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your regex fails because the `\b` can never match. It matches only between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters; therefore it can never match between `\w*` and `[A-Z]` or another `\w*`.

So, you need some other (=non-alphanumeric) characters between your words:

Try

```
(\w*)\W+([A-Z][a-z]\w*)\W+(\w*)
```

although (if your regex engine allows using Unicode properties), you might be happier with

```
(\w*)\W+(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\w*)\W+(\w*)
```

As written, only capitalized words of length 2 or more are matched, i. e. "I" (as in "me") will not be matched by this. I suppose you inserted the `[a-z]` to avoid matches like "IBM"? Or what was your intention?